# Creating hash of hash on the fly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'd like to be able to create a hash of hash, but when I do

```
var checkState = {}
for (let i in ['a','b','c']) {
  checkState[i]          = null
  checkState[i]['state'] = null
}

console.log(checkState)
```

I get

```
(node:27532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'state' of undefined
```

For some reason `checkState[i]` is ok, but `checkState[i]['state']` is not.

## Question

Can anyone explain how I can create a hash of hash?

Comment: I’m confused what your question has to do with the error you’re seeing

Comment: Try writing `checkState[i] = {}` instead of `checkState[i] = null`. The issue appears to be that you are setting a property of a value which is null - it needs to be a non-null type to assign a value to a property. Alternately replace both lines with `checkState[i] = { state: null }`. Also, FYI in JavaScript these are called objects, not hashes/dictionaries, to avoid confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attempt of retreiving property of null (or undefined) causes TypeError, so use an empty object instead:

```js
for (let i in ['a','b','c']) {
  checkState[i]          = {}
  checkState[i]['state'] = null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Things to note down

```
var checkState = {}
for (let i in ['a','b','c']) {
  checkState[i]          = null // this line assign checkState.a = null
// so after above line object is checkState = { a : null}
  checkState[i]['state'] = null // this line now trying to access 
//state property on a which is null( undefined), so this throws error. 
}

console.log(checkState)
```

you need to modify your code accordingly to get rid of this

modified code

```
var checkState = {}
for (let i in ['a','b','c']) {
  checkState[i]          = {} // assigned an empty object
  checkState[i]['state'] = null
}

console.log(checkState)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for shorter recording

```js
const checkState = ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: { state: null } }), {});

console.log(checkState);
```